# How could I solve this Deepcopy Problem of this code?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to use this model after fetching it from GitHub and making some modifications.
I tried to define the model as shown below and attempted to deepcopy it, but encountered the mentioned error.

```
import copy

model = ViViTBackbone(
    t=24,
    h=112,
    w=112,
    patch_t=4,
    patch_h=7,
    patch_w=7,
    num_classes=500,
    dim=1024,
    depth=6,
    heads=10,
    mlp_dim=8,
    model=3
)
target_model = copy.deepcopy(model)
```

However, I encounter an error like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 2
      1 import copy
----> 2 target_model = copy.deepcopy(model)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/el_dorado/lib/python3.8/copy.py:172, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    170                 y = x
    171             else:
--> 172                 y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
    174 # If is its own copy, don't memoize.
    175 if y is not x:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/el_dorado/lib/python3.8/copy.py:270, in _reconstruct(x, memo, func, args, state, listiter, dictiter, deepcopy)
    268 if state is not None:
    269     if deep:
--> 270         state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    271     if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    272         y.__setstate__(state)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/el_dorado/lib/python3.8/copy.py:146, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    144 copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    145 if copier is not None:
--> 146     y = copier(x, memo)
    147 else:
    148     if issubclass(cls, type):

File ~/anaconda3/envs/el_dorado/lib/python3.8/copy.py:230, in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo, deepcopy)
    228 memo[id(x)] = y
    229 for key, value in x.items():
--> 230     y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    231 return y

File ~/anaconda3/envs/el_dorado/lib/python3.8/copy.py:153, in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    151 copier = getattr(x, "__deepcopy__", None)
    152 if copier is not None:
--> 153     y = copier(memo)
    154 else:
    155     reductor = dispatch_table.get(cls)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/el_dorado/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py:86, in Tensor.__deepcopy__(self, memo)
     84     return handle_torch_function(Tensor.__deepcopy__, (self,), self, memo)
     85 if not self.is_leaf:
---> 86     raise RuntimeError(
     87         "Only Tensors created explicitly by the user "
     88         "(graph leaves) support the deepcopy protocol at the moment.  "
     89         "If you were attempting to deepcopy a module, this may be because "
     90         "of a torch.nn.utils.weight_norm usage, "
     91         "see https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/103001"
     92     )
     93 if id(self) in memo:
     94     return memo[id(self)]

RuntimeError: Only Tensors created explicitly by the user (graph leaves) support the deepcopy protocol at the moment.  If you were attempting to deepcopy a module, this may be because of a torch.nn.utils.weight_norm usage, see https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/103001
```

and deepcopy doesn't work. Could you please help? Below is the original code.
(refer github : https://github.com/drv-agwl/ViViT-pytorch/blob/master/models.py )

```
from torch import nn, einsum
import torch
from einops.layers.torch import Rearrange
from einops import rearrange, repeat

class PreNorm(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim, fn):
        super().__init__()
        self.norm = nn.LayerNorm(dim)
        self.fn = fn

    def forward(self, x, **kwargs):
        return self.fn(self.norm(x), **kwargs)


class FSAttention(nn.Module):
    """Factorized Self-Attention"""

    def __init__(self, dim, heads=8, dim_head=64, dropout=0.):
        super().__init__()
        inner_dim = dim_head * heads
        project_out = not (heads == 1 and dim_head == dim)

        self.heads = heads
        self.scale = dim_head ** -0.5

        self.attend = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)
        self.to_qkv = nn.Linear(dim, inner_dim * 3, bias=False)

        self.to_out = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(inner_dim, dim),
            nn.Dropout(dropout)
        ) if project_out else nn.Identity()

    def forward(self, x):
        b, n, _, h = *x.shape, self.heads
        qkv = self.to_qkv(x).chunk(3, dim=-1)
        q, k, v = map(lambda t: rearrange(t, 'b n (h d) -> b h n d', h=h), qkv)

        dots = einsum('b h i d, b h j d -> b h i j', q, k) * self.scale

        attn = self.attend(dots)

        out = einsum('b h i j, b h j d -> b h i d', attn, v)
        out = rearrange(out, 'b h n d -> b n (h d)')
        return self.to_out(out)


class FDAttention(nn.Module):
    """Factorized Dot-product Attention"""

    def __init__(self, dim, nt, nh, nw, heads=8, dim_head=64, dropout=0.):
        super().__init__()
        inner_dim = dim_head * heads
        project_out = not (heads == 1 and dim_head == dim)

        self.nt = nt
        self.nh = nh
        self.nw = nw

        self.heads = heads
        self.scale = dim_head ** -0.5

        self.attend = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)
        self.to_qkv = nn.Linear(dim, inner_dim * 3, bias=False)

        self.to_out = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(inner_dim, dim),
            nn.Dropout(dropout)
        ) if project_out else nn.Identity()

    def forward(self, x):
        b, n, d, h = *x.shape, self.heads

        qkv = self.to_qkv(x).chunk(3, dim=-1)
        q, k, v = map(lambda t: rearrange(t, 'b n (h d) -> b h n d', h=h), qkv)
        qs, qt = q.chunk(2, dim=1)
        ks, kt = k.chunk(2, dim=1)
        vs, vt = v.chunk(2, dim=1)

        # Attention over spatial dimension
        qs = qs.view(b, h // 2, self.nt, self.nh * self.nw, -1)
        ks, vs = ks.view(b, h // 2, self.nt, self.nh * self.nw, -1), vs.view(b, h // 2, self.nt, self.nh * self.nw, -1)
        spatial_dots = einsum('b h t i d, b h t j d -> b h t i j', qs, ks) * self.scale
        sp_attn = self.attend(spatial_dots)
        spatial_out = einsum('b h t i j, b h t j d -> b h t i d', sp_attn, vs)

        # Attention over temporal dimension
        qt = qt.view(b, h // 2, self.nh * self.nw, self.nt, -1)
        kt, vt = kt.view(b, h // 2, self.nh * self.nw, self.nt, -1), vt.view(b, h // 2, self.nh * self.nw, self.nt, -1)
        temporal_dots = einsum('b h s i d, b h s j d -> b h s i j', qt, kt) * self.scale
        temporal_attn = self.attend(temporal_dots)
        temporal_out = einsum('b h s i j, b h s j d -> b h s i d', temporal_attn, vt)

        # return self.to_out(out)


class FeedForward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim, hidden_dim, dropout=0.):
        super().__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(dim, hidden_dim),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Dropout(dropout),
            nn.Linear(hidden_dim, dim),
            nn.Dropout(dropout)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net(x)


class FSATransformerEncoder(nn.Module):
    """Factorized Self-Attention Transformer Encoder"""

    def __init__(self, dim, depth, heads, dim_head, mlp_dim, nt, nh, nw, dropout=0.):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([])
        self.nt = nt
        self.nh = nh
        self.nw = nw

        for _ in range(depth):
            self.layers.append(nn.ModuleList(
                [PreNorm(dim, FSAttention(dim, heads=heads, dim_head=dim_head, dropout=dropout)),
                 PreNorm(dim, FSAttention(dim, heads=heads, dim_head=dim_head, dropout=dropout)),
                 PreNorm(dim, FeedForward(dim, mlp_dim, dropout=dropout))
                 ]))

    def forward(self, x):

        b = x.shape[0]
        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=0, end_dim=1)  # extract spatial tokens from x

        for sp_attn, temp_attn, ff in self.layers:
            sp_attn_x = sp_attn(x) + x  # Spatial attention

            # Reshape tensors for temporal attention
            sp_attn_x = sp_attn_x.chunk(b, dim=0)
            sp_attn_x = [temp[None] for temp in sp_attn_x]
            sp_attn_x = torch.cat(sp_attn_x, dim=0).transpose(1, 2)
            sp_attn_x = torch.flatten(sp_attn_x, start_dim=0, end_dim=1)

            temp_attn_x = temp_attn(sp_attn_x) + sp_attn_x  # Temporal attention

            x = ff(temp_attn_x) + temp_attn_x  # MLP

            # Again reshape tensor for spatial attention
            x = x.chunk(b, dim=0)
            x = [temp[None] for temp in x]
            x = torch.cat(x, dim=0).transpose(1, 2)
            x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=0, end_dim=1)

        # Reshape vector to [b, nt*nh*nw, dim]
        x = x.chunk(b, dim=0)
        x = [temp[None] for temp in x]
        x = torch.cat(x, dim=0)
        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1, end_dim=2)
        return x


class FDATransformerEncoder(nn.Module):
    """Factorized Dot-product Attention Transformer Encoder"""

    def __init__(self, dim, depth, heads, dim_head, mlp_dim, nt, nh, nw, dropout=0.):
        super().__init__()
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([])
        self.nt = nt
        self.nh = nh
        self.nw = nw

        for _ in range(depth):
            self.layers.append(
                PreNorm(dim, FDAttention(dim, nt, nh, nw, heads=heads, dim_head=dim_head, dropout=dropout)))

    def forward(self, x):
        for attn in self.layers:
            x = attn(x) + x

        return x


class ViViTBackbone(nn.Module):
    """ Model-3 backbone of ViViT """

    def __init__(self, t, h, w, patch_t, patch_h, patch_w, num_classes, dim, depth, heads, mlp_dim, dim_head=3,
                 channels=3, mode='tubelet', device='cuda', emb_dropout=0., dropout=0., model=3):
        super().__init__()

        assert t % patch_t == 0 and h % patch_h == 0 and w % patch_w == 0, "Video dimensions should be divisible by " \
                                                                           "tubelet size "

        self.T = t
        self.H = h
        self.W = w
        self.channels = channels
        self.t = patch_t
        self.h = patch_h
        self.w = patch_w
        self.mode = mode
        self.device = device

        self.nt = self.T // self.t
        self.nh = self.H // self.h
        self.nw = self.W // self.w

        tubelet_dim = self.t * self.h * self.w * channels

        # x.shape: torch.Size([64, 3, 32, 64, 64]) -> torch.Size([64, 32, 64, 64, 3])
        self.to_tubelet_embedding = nn.Sequential(
            Rearrange('b c (t pt) (h ph) (w pw) -> b t (h w) (pt ph pw c)', pt=self.t, ph=self.h, pw=self.w),
            nn.Linear(tubelet_dim, dim)
        )

        # repeat same spatial position encoding temporally
        self.pos_embedding = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, 1, self.nh * self.nw, dim)).repeat(1, self.nt, 1, 1)

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(emb_dropout)

        if model == 3:
            self.transformer = FSATransformerEncoder(dim, depth, heads, dim_head, mlp_dim,
                                                     self.nt, self.nh, self.nw, dropout)
        elif model == 4:
            assert heads % 2 == 0, "Number of heads should be even"
            self.transformer = FDATransformerEncoder(dim, depth, heads, dim_head, mlp_dim,
                                                     self.nt, self.nh, self.nw, dropout)

        self.to_latent = nn.Identity()

        self.mlp_head = nn.Sequential(
            nn.LayerNorm(dim),
            nn.Linear(dim, num_classes)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        """ x is a video: (b, C, T, H, W) """
        tokens = self.to_tubelet_embedding(x)

        self.pos_embedding = self.pos_embedding.to(tokens.device)
        
        tokens += self.pos_embedding
        tokens = self.dropout(tokens)

        x = self.transformer(tokens) # output dimension: [b, nt*nh*nw, dim]
        
        b, _, _ = x.shape
        x = x.view(b, self.nt, self.nh*self.nw, -1).mean(dim=2)  # 공간적 차원에 대한 평균

        x = self.to_latent(x)
        
        return x
```

I've made some modifications to the output, and I attempted to use clone(), but it seems difficult because I'm using something called Hydra. Nonetheless, deepcopy should work.

Comment: Your code seems to be an arbitrary part of a larger product, and seems to contain a lot of code not related to the problem. Please provide code that allows someone to reproduce the issue, or be more specific about how and when the issue comes about.

Comment: I added more comments in post

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).